# PDO Exception in getting item id's

Tags: php, drupal, pdo, drupal-7

I am trying to get item `id`'s from `wn_new_items` and i am using below query to get required result. But somehow i am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
```

**Here is my code:**

```
$table1 = db_select('wn_category', 'c');
    $table1->join('wn_item_categories', 'ic', 'c.id = ic.category_id');
    $table1->join('wn_auction_item', 'i', 'i.id = ic.item_id');
    $table1->leftJoin('wn_new_items', 'ni', 'i.id = ni.item_id');
    $table1->fields('i', array('id'));

    $table2 = clone $table1;
    $table1->condition('i.is_posted', 1);
    $table1->condition('i.is_unposted', 0);
    $table1->condition('i.item_status', array('Direct Sales', 'Received In Inventory'));
    $table1->condition('c.type', 'category');

    $table2->condition('i.is_posted', 0);
    $table2->condition('i.is_unposted', 1);
    $table2->condition('i.item_status', array('Sold'));
    $table2->where('i.date_ordered > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY))');

    $query = \Database::getConnection()
                      ->select($table1->union($table2))
                      ->fields(NULL, array('id'))
                      ->execute();

    $ids = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('id');
```